# Add class based on current page filename without file extension

Tags: html, jquery, css, filenames

I want to add a class based on the current page file name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $( "html" ).addClass( filename );
});
```

...produces

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="server.php">
```

How can I strip the file extension so that I end up with...

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="server">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string by `.` and return everything but the last section:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split('.')
    if (filename.length != 1) filename.pop()
    $( "html" ).addClass( filename.join('-'));
});
```

Comment: Not bad, except if the filename has more than one period/dot `.` in it: `this.file.php` would come out as "this" not as "this.file" -- on top of that, "this.file" would cause problems with CSS selectors, so you should transform dots to dashes, to get "this-file". Use `lastIndexOf` for the dot too, like it's used for the slash `/`

Comment: Very nice edit! Now I'll steal that and make it a function that takes a url and returns the generated class name.